# Nuxtjs login errors are not handling properly

Tags: authentication, error-handling, nuxt.js, http-status-code-404, snackbar

I have used auth-nuxt for authentication

This is my login method

```
 async handleLogin(loginData) {
      try {
        const login = {
          email: loginData.email,
          username: loginData.email,
          password: loginData.password
        }
        let response = await this.$auth.loginWith('local', { data: login })
        console.log('response', response)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error Response', e.response)
      }
    }
```

For other status code than 200 response is not handled at catch. Instead it is catching at then hook. And response value in console.is false

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        token: {
          property: 'data.accessToken',
          type: 'Bearer',
          maxAge: 'data.expiresIn'
          // 1800, // Token expiration time in seconds (30 minutes)
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'data.refreshToken',
          data: 'refreshToken',
          maxAge: false
          // 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, // Refresh token expiration time in seconds (30 days)
        },
        user: {
          property: false,
          autoFetch: false
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/admin/auth/login',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'data.accessToken'
          },
          refresh: { url: '/refresh', method: 'post' },
          user: {
            url: '/admin/user-info',
            method: 'get',
            propertyName: 'data'
          },
          logout: '/admin/auth/logout' // Optional, if your backend doesn't have a logout endpoint
        },
        // autoFetchUser: true
      }
    },
    // Set autoRefresh option to true
    // autoRefresh: true,
    // autoLogout: true, // Optional, if you want to automatically log out when the access token expires
    redirect: {
      login: '/sign-in', // if login required
      logout: '/sign-in', // after logout
      home: '/' // after login
    }
  },
```

Also even for these errors it automatically calls user-info api

I have tried dfiierent ways but error is always catching in then hook

```
handleLogin(loginData) {
    this.$auth
      .loginWith('local', {
        data: {
          email: loginData.email,
          username: loginData.email,
          password: loginData.password
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // The promise is resolved, but we need to check the status of the response
        if (response && response.status === 200) {
          // Successful login
          console.log('Login API response:', response)
          this.snackbartext = 'Logged in successfully'
          this.snackbar = true
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.$router.push('/')
          }, 1000)
        } else {
          // Login failed, handle the error
          console.error('Login API error:', response)
          this.snackbartext = 'An error occurred during login. Please try again.'
          this.snackbar = true
          // Handle other error scenarios, if needed
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // The promise is rejected (login failed)
        console.error('Login API error:', error)
        this.snackbartext = 'An error occurred during login. Please try again.'
        this.snackbar = true
        // Handle other error scenarios, if needed
      })
  }
```

I need to show snackbar when api response is not 200 instead showing error page